# Is obtaining maximum likelihood estimate of Gaussian mixture via clustering possible?

Tags: clustering, maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Let's say I have a data set $ X = \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ with underlying probability density
$$ p(x; \mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2) = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i p(x; \mu_i, \sigma_i^2), \quad \sum \alpha_i = 1 , \alpha_i \geq 0,$$
where $p(x; \mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$ is the probability density of the normal distribution with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$. Let's assume we don't know the parameters $\mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2$ of the probability density and we want to find the parameters that approximate the probability distribution of $X$ in the best way, i.e. the goal is to maximize the log-likelihood function
$$
\mathcal{L} (\mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2|X) = \ln (P (\mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2 | x_1, \dots, x_n)) = \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(p(x_j; \mu_1, \sigma_1^2, \dots, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2)).
$$
For that, one usually uses the Expectation Maximization Algorithm. Now, as soon as we have a maximum likelihood estimation $\hat{\theta}=(\hat{\mu}_1, \hat{\sigma}_1^2, \dots, \hat{\mu}_k, \hat{\sigma}_k^2)$, we could cluster our data set via
$$ x \text{ belongs to cluster }i \iff i = argmax_{j \in \{1, \dots, k \} } \alpha_j p(x; \hat{\mu}_i, \hat{\sigma}_i^2) = argmax_{j \in \{1, \dots, k \} } \alpha_j \ln(p(x; \hat{\mu}_i, \hat{\sigma}_i^2)).$$

My question is, if we can obtain a maximum likelihood estimation $\hat{\theta}$, if we  partition our data set into $k$ clusters $S_1, ..., S_k$, such that
$$ \sum_{i=1,...,k} \alpha_i \mathcal{L(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2| S_i)} $$ is maximised. We would then obtain the estimates $\hat{\mu}_i, \hat{\sigma}_i^2$ with the formula for maximum likelihood estimates for normal distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters), namely
$$ \hat{\mu}_i = \frac{1}{|S_i|}\sum_{x \in s_i} x \quad\text{ and } \quad\hat{\sigma}_i^2 = \frac{1}{|S_i|} \sum_{x \in s_i} (x - \mu_i)^2.$$

EDIT:

I have read that the Gaussian mixture model(GMM) can be seen as a generalisation of k-means. In k-means we want to find the means $\mu_1, ..., \mu_k$ so that
$$\sum_x \min_{i=1,...,k} \| x - \mu_i \|^2 \quad(1)$$ is minimized.
This yields us cluster $S_1, ..., S_k$, where $S_i$ consists of all data points $x$ with
$$\|x - \mu_i\| \leq \|x - \mu_j\|, \text{for all } j \neq i. $$
Up to a scalar and additional components that are independent of the clustering, equation (1) is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{i=1,...,k} \mathcal{L}(\mu_i, 1|S_i). \quad(2)$$
so for k-means we can consider all possible clusterings, and pick the clustering, so that (2) is minimal.
Therefore, I thought that we can somehow do the same with GMM.

Comment: I do not understand what you are proposing. Maximising the completed likelihood in both the parameters and the cluster allocations will result in a different estimation and most likely overfitting, e.g., some one observation components.

Comment: @Xi'an I have edited my question, to provide more details.